# Enabling hidden Georgian keyboard in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, keyboard, georgian

In iOS 5 beta simulator I saw that Apple made a native Georgian keyboard for iOS. But in the final version of iOS 5 Apple made this keyboard hidden. I found a solution to turn on this keyboard by changing GlobalPreferences.plist file located in `private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`: just add a `ka@hw=Georgian;sw=Georgian` and restart the system. Now I want to make an app that will enable this keyboard automatically without changing this file manually. How can I do this?

Here is the image of keyboard itself:

[image: keyboard]

And the "GlobalPreferences.plist" file code, changed to reveal keyboard:

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/2r3d3v3L35241Q3a1G02/plist.png]

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?  What does Google give you for "objective-c modify plist"?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find specified file I used "iBackupBot for iTunes" v 4.1.5 Here are the steps to follow:

1- backup your iphone via itunes to your pc
2- run iBackupBot for iTunes
3- find the file *GlobalPreferences.plist* (System Files --> Home Domain --> Library --> Preferences)
4- just add ka@hw=Georgian;sw=Georgian as shown above and save the file
5- restore your *backup* (NOT THE IPHONE)

You're done

Answer (score 0):

I can find this specific file. I have the last version 511 and can't find this

```
private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
```